# HTML/Javascript Forms Input text then generate at bottom

Tags: javascript, html

Creating HTML Forms, So here's what i needed. I want to input text on the box then Show the inputted text to the bottom of submit button.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp - Site of the Code

I just want to have the inputted text show on the bottom so that i could copy it. But instead when i click submit it redirects me to an url,

Im gonna need multiple forms like name,age,date of birth,phone number,status. Forms.

Please kindly help me thanks!

Comment: What is your current code?

Comment: `<form name="myWebForm" action="mailto:youremail@email.com" method="post">
First: <input title="Please Enter Your First Name" id="first" name="first" type="text" size="12" /><br />
Last: <input title="Please Enter Your Last Name" id="last" name="last" type="text" size="18" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>` Tried This One but submit ends up to sending email or something i just want it to show on the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="txt">
    <button type="button" onclick="ShowText();">Submit</button>
</form>
<span id="show"></span>
<script>
    function ShowText(){
        var txt = document.getElementById('txt');
        var show = document.getElementById('show');
        show.innerHTML = txt.value;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes Thats the idea! Thanks now i need help on the forms, i want to add name,age,date of birth,phone number,status, etc. I want it to show on bottom. Or just create a box on the bottom where it'll show my inputted text so that its easy to copy.

Comment: Absolutely, you can do the same with this solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanna show like the firstname and the last name you could do this:

```js
function enter(){
var firstname = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
var lastname = document.getElementById("lastName").value;

document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = firstname + " " + lastname;
  }
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="firstName"> 
  <input type="text" id="lastName">
  <input type="submit" onclick="enter()" value="Submit">
 </form>
  <div id="show"></div>
```

Comment: But its like 6 more boxes i needed for like age, location etc.

Comment: You can basicly add new inputs like `<input type="text" id="phone">` etc. and than in javascript after last name `+ " " + phone;` etc. But I strongly recommend you to store it in a object. I don't know how much you know about javascript though.

Comment: Basically a little but can you give me sample like 5 inputs then i'll figure out the rest. and also one question on the generated text on the bottom is it possible to put it in a box so that i could easily copy it it like ctrl+a. Thanks!